# using emberJs with xampp

Tags: ember.js, xampp

Can I use emberJS with Xampp?

To be honest most of the tutorials that I encountered uses RoR as their server. So I'm really having trouble where to start. I'd like to try to develop some simple apps like registrations. But I have no idea how to use and access mysql databases thru emberjs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use EmberJS with Xampp.

In fact EmberJS works quite well by itself with no server sitting behind it. You could simply serve your Ember App from Apache. Here is a good article talking abut a Ember app that is just standalone and doesn't run on top of a server. http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html

If you want to access data in a MySQL database, then you would probably want to have some kind of server (PHP or Ruby on Rails or Java or Django etc.) that accesses the database and makes web services available for the Ember.js app to interact with.

In terms of communicating with the server you can write your own code for interacting with the web services provided by your server, or if you are looking to do CRUD on some entities, you should look into Ember-Data which is an add-on for Ember.JS which helps you to access a set of Restful web services to CRUD entities persisted on the server.

In case you're interested here is an example of a Ember.JS app using a Node.js backend. You could apply the same principles to your Xampp stack
https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences

Update 30/08/2013: Ember-App-Kit is a great attempt to create a standardised ember app structure with a build process and testing built in. That actually generates static files that don't even need to be hosted on a server stack. You can just put your app on S3, or server it using Apache/Nginx... https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit
Ember-tools does a similar thing. These two projects might merge at some point. https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-tools